# How to factorize quadratic equations quickly?

Tags: quadratics

It takes me more than a minute to quickly factorise this kind of quadratic expression.
$$3n^2 -53n + 232$$

I need to solve them in less than $10$-$15$ seconds. Please tell me a way I can solve them.

Comment: After using the prime factorisation of $3$ and $232$, it just comes down to observing that $3\times 8+1\times 29=53$.

Comment: Since you are asking for this kind of equation in general, you are out of luck. Use the quadratic formula and a calculator, if you want to get a result in under 15 seconds.

Comment: I have an exam to give without using calculators.

Comment: @JC12 I hope prime factorisation doesn’t take much of my time .I will try it.Thnx

Comment: Use the quadratic formula. Even without a calculator, it's probably the fastest way to go. I don't know if you can get it down to 15 seconds though.

Comment: Please use MathJax for all equations on this site. There's a tutorial with lots of examples at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I'm terribly sorry! My previous edit lost the 3 coefficient of the leading term. :(

Comment: See if the [AC-method](https://www.google.com/search?q=fractor+%22ac+method%22) works better for you than other methods. *(moments later)* I see @JTP - Apologise to Monica has mentioned this method. I thought I had glanced at all the answers before writing this comment, but apparently I didn't scroll down far enough.

Answer (score 7):

$$3n^2 -53n + 232$$

I use a process called "A-C Method", "Grouping", or "Split the Middle Term".

$$3*232=696$$

Now, what two numbers add to -53 but multiply to 696?

$-23 * -30 $? That's $690$. Close.

Now, keep in mind, (a+b)(a-b) is a maximum when b=0. Therefore, since we are at $690$, and wish a higher result, the numbers need to get closer, so we just move by 1, since $690$ was so close to $696$.

$-24 * -29 $? That's it! Second guess.

$$3n^2-24n-29n+232$$  (we split the middle term so the 24 is a nice multiple of 3)

$$(3n^2-24n)-(29n-232)$$ (Now, we group, and be mindful of that minus)

$$3n(n-8)-29(n-8)$$

$$(3n-29)(n-8)$$

Will update/edit if OP needs clarification.

Comment: You don’t which way to go then.You may think 65*12 as well and go the other way.So to not do that, I wanted a quicker trick and not make mistake in the way you’re going.

Comment: @robertpatrick - of course I do. (a+b)(a-b) gets larger as b goes to zero. If I failed to articulate that, I should edit it in. But the process itself is 2-3 guesses, tops. (Update, I edited a note for clarity)

Comment: @PM2Ring - Yes. I am 58 and work in a HS, a second chapter, post retirement. As a student, it was guess and check. In my second year in the HS, a student showed me this, and I have used it ever since. 2/3 of students embrace it, and about 1/3 reject it respectfully, as Robert seems to have done. My approach is that there are many ways to solve a problem. Find the method you are most comfortable and successful with.

Comment: I didn’t understand what you meant there.I want to know how were so sure of using the numbers the way you did and not the way I did.I use the same method but am not getting it when I go the wrong way.

Comment: @robertpatrick - sorry, I missed something. 65+12=77. Since the last term is positive and middle term negative, we need two numbers, both negative, summing to -53.

Comment: The two numbers must sum to a known value, here, -53. Whatever 2 numbers you pick, you have a product as well. To get the product to move higher, bring the numbers closer, to go lower, move the numbers further away. The truth is, once you understand the process, with a bit of practice, the result comes very fast.

Answer (score 2):

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$
where$$x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a};\;x_2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: I didn’t understand it.How would you use it for my questions.

Comment: @robertpatrick You didn't say what level are you in math. Another tricky way is $$3 n^2 - 29 n - 24 n + 232=3n(n-8)-29(n-8)=(n-8)(3n-29)$$

Comment: How did you find that 24 and 29 are those numbers sir.

Comment: @robertpatrick I told you it was tricky. Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Ok thank you for help

Comment: @Raffaele - I can't help but wonder. And this comment is really with MathEducators.SE in mind.  Would a teacher be okay with this? We teach quadratic equation. We teach factoring, by a couple different methods. But, if a student was asked to factor, and 'show work', this might not be accepted.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica  What are you talking about? This formula is on ALL the books I have worked with in 40 years of high school teaching. OP didn't specify what they wanted, just to solve in 10-15 seconds and with this formula you can make it

Comment: @Raffaele - I am talking about the teacher, who, right or wrong, tells student to factor, and when the roots are found and substituted into factored form, as you suggest, the student is marked wrong. You give no warning to OP to discard irrational roots, which a teacher would surely reject if they asked the student to factor, as opposed to solving roots.

Answer (score 2):

As Raffaele says, it's tricky when the leading coefficient isn't $1$, or a perfect square. Especially if you don't know if the expression is reducible or not. You can tell that by looking at the discriminant, $b^2-4ac$, but if you've gone that far, you might as well eliminate all the guesswork and just use the quadratic formula. ;)

But anyway, assuming it is factorisable, because $3$ is prime, $-53<0$ and $232>0$, we know the factors must be of the form
$$(3n-u)(n-v)$$
with $3v+u=53$ and $uv=232$ for $u,v>0$.

Now $232=8\cdot29$ and any multiple of $29>53$, which eliminates all possibilities except $3v+29=53$. Thus $u=29$ and $v=8$, so the desired factorisation is
$$(3n-29)(n-8)$$

---

Another approach is to complete the square, but it is a bit tedious, and the numbers may get too large for rapid mental calculation.

We need the leading coeffient to be a square, and the coefficient of the $n$ term to be even. So we have to multiply this expression by $12$. Thus
$$36n^2 - 12\cdot53n + 12\cdot8\cdot29$$
$$(6n)^2 - 2\cdot6\cdot53n + 53^2 - 53^2 + 12\cdot8\cdot29$$
$$(6n-53)^2 - (53^2 - 12\cdot8\cdot29)$$
That constant term looks pretty bad, until we notice that $53=29+24$ and $4\cdot24=12\cdot8$
$$(6n-53)^2 - ((29+24)^2 - 4\cdot24\cdot29)$$
$$(6n-53)^2 - (29-24)^2$$
$$(6n-53)^2 - 5^2$$
$$(6n-53+5)(6n-53-5)$$
$$(6n-48)(6n-58)$$
$$12(n-8)(3n-29)$$
And now we can drop that multiplier of $12$
$$(n-8)(3n-29)$$

As I said, it's a bit tedious, but we got there eventually. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps you.
If $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ has a rational solution $\frac p q$ then $p\mid c$ and $q\mid a$.
So if
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ then the only integer solutions are divisors of $232$ because $3$ is prime.
We have $232=2^3\cdot 29$. So the divisors are $\{\pm 1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm 8\, \pm 29, \pm2 \cdot 29, \pm4 \cdot 29, \pm 8 \cdot 29\}$

If we have an integer solution $x_1$, the numerator $p$ of the other solution $x_2=\frac p q$ is a divisor of $232$,  too, and it satisfies $$53-3\cdot x_1=p\in D$$. From this we see that 53-3*8=29$ asns so $8$ is the solution.

But all in all I think using the formula

$$x_1=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2};\;x_2=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2}$$

is the most efficient way. Calculating $b^2-4ac$ shouldn't be a problem, and calculating the square root of a 4 digit number is also rather simple. It is a two digit number. The left digit can be estimated by comparing the size of the numbr to $10^2,20^2,...$ and the right digit can be estimated by  comparing the squares modulo $10$.