# Quickest way to solve $x^2+(30-14\mathrm i)x=240$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, complex-numbers, quadratics

> I want the quickest way to solve for $x$ in $x^2+(30-14\mathrm i)x=240$. Moreover, is there any method that can solve quadratics with complex coefficients quickly?

Here, quick/slow are assessed based on the time needed to work entirely by hand.

The slow method is,
\[(x-7\mathrm i+15)^2=416-210\mathrm i.\]
Then we calculate the square root of the magnitude and half the argument of $416-210\mathrm i$, which took about $6$ minutes to do by hand. The roots are $x=12\mathrm i-36$ or $x=6+2\mathrm i$.

Comment: In general,  the quickest way is to give it to Mathematica

Comment: What's wrong with quadratic formula? Of course, it's essentially the same as completing the square, but it skips over the manual work.

Comment: Note that $210=2\times 21\times 5$ and $416=21^2-5^2$ so you immediately get $21-5i$ as a square-root.

Comment: To expand on what user10354138 said, you are looking for solutions of $(a+bi)^2 = 416 -210i$, for real $a,b$, which is equivalent to solving $a^2-b^2 = 416,\ 2ab = -210$. Of course, finding one solution gives you the other immediately, since you take the additive inverse.

Comment: This is no different from factoring an ordinary quadratic, except that now you have the additional arithmetic of $i$. Use the quadratic formula, complete the square, or find by inspection numbers satisfying $r+s=b/a$ and $rs=c/a$, and so on. Practice factoring and mental arithmetic and you can get quicker. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3879007/how-to-factorize-quadratic-equations-quickly).

Comment: Let $\,x - 7\,i + 15 = a + b\,i\,$ then $\,a^2 - b^2 = 416\,$ by equating the real parts, and $\,a^2 + b^2$ $= \sqrt{416^2 + 210^2} = 466\,$ by equating the magnitudes, so $\,a^2 = (416 + 466) / 2$ $= 441\,$, or $\,a = \pm 21\,$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2-(-30+14i)x-240=0$$
A good question for students/youth. If the roots are $x_1=a+bi$ and $x_2=c+di$ then by Vieta's formulas
$$x_1+x_2=(a+c)+(b+d)i=-30+14i$$
$$x_1x_2=(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i=-240+0i$$
$$a+c=-30$$
$$b+d=14$$
$$ac-bd=-240$$
$$ad+bc=0$$
From the last equation $c=-ka, d=kb$. Hence,
$$(k-1)a=30$$
$$(k+1)b=14$$
$$k(a^2+b^2)=240.$$
By guessing $k=6,a=6,b=2$.
Answer: $x_1=6+2i$, $x_2=-36+12i.$